# SQL - CASE Multiple variables in single condition

Tags: sql, case

I have something similar to below in my SQL that I am looking to simplify the CASE WHEN statement
I have multiple variables (i.e. CODE1, CODE2, all the way through CODE10 that I want to run through a CASE WHEN any of those codes are found in my "CODES" table to create a "CODE_FLAG" variable.

TABLE2 would contain a list of codes (that might be updated some day).
So end result would be Selecting all records from Table1 as well as a created variable called CODE_FLAG that is simply a 'Y' or 'N' based on the list found in TABLE2.  TABLE1 has up to 10 Codes listed as CODE1, CODE2, CODE3...etc.

**TABLE2**

| CODES |
| --- |
| 98761234 |
| 43216789 |
| 11111111 |

Here's what I have so far.  Is there a way to

```
WITH T2,
(Select CODES
FROM TABLE2)

SELECT  T1.*,
CASE WHEN T1.CODE1, T1.CODE2, T1.CODE3, T1.CODE4 IN (T2.CODES) 
THEN 'Y', ELSE 'N' END AS CODE_FLAG
FROM TABLE1 T1
CROSS JOIN T2 T2
```

or maybe something like this?

```
WITH T2,
(Select CODES
FROM TABLE2)

SELECT  T1.*,
CASE WHEN T1.CODE1 or T1.CODE2 or T1.CODE3 or T1.CODE4 IN (select T2.CODES from T2 T2) 
THEN 'Y', ELSE 'N' END AS CODE_FLAG
FROM TABLE1 T1
```

I currently have a much longer version

```
WITH T2,
(Select CODES
FROM TABLE2)

SELECT  T1.*,
CASE WHEN T1.CODE1 in (select CODES from T2) 
or T1.CODE2 in (select CODES from T2)
or T1.CODE3 in (select CODES from T2)
or T1.CODE4 in (select CODES from T2) 
THEN 'Y', ELSE 'N' END AS CODE_FLAG
FROM TABLE1 T1
```

Comment: You know it's an SQL question when the title is all uppercase.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.) Simplify! [mcve].

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: Join Table1 to a temorary table containing t2.codes?? Agreed though, need to see an example really.

Comment: I've never seen the SQL2003 `case` expression format supported anywhere, what RDBMS is it?

Comment: This would be a much easier solution if your data was properly normalised with codes stored as rows, becomes a simple join correlation then!

Comment: Does the number of code1,code2 fileds stay at 10, or can it be any amount up to 10?  You could `UNPIVOT` them and do a join

Comment: @nathan_sav Even with a normalised format and a JOIN, one record in T1 could match multiple records in T2, which would be messy in terms of adding one column to each row without duplicating rows. As such, it naturally lends itself to a simple EXISTS() check.

Answer (score 2):

Use an EXISTS() check.

```
SELECT
  *,
  CASE WHEN EXISTS (
      SELECT *
      FROM T2
      WHERE T2.codes IN (T1.code1, T1.code2, T1.code3, T1.code4)
    )
  THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END   AS code_flag
FROM
  T1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your table structure normalization does not appear to be a good design having multiple references of a same context code in one row is not good.  It should be more of a parent/child relationship.  Something like

```
MainTable
id  someName  someOtherThing, etc
1   Bill      a
2   Linda     x
3   Mark      s
```

Have a secondary table of the different lookup codes you are interested in capturing/having purpose for

```
LookupCode
id  LookupCode
1   Code1
2   Code8
3   Code74
```

Then, have a third table associated by the main ID in your first table and the codes it could have.

```
MainTableCodes
id   MainTableID   LookupCodeID
1    1             1
2    1             3
3    2             2
4    3             2
5    3             3
```

Then, you could do a join (required), or LEFT JOIN (not required) to see if something exists or not such as

```
select
      mt.id,
      lc.LookupCode
   from
      MainTable mt
         LEFT JOIN MainTableCodes mtc
            on mt.id = mtc.MainTableID
            LEFT JOIN LookupCode lc
               on mtc.LookupCodeID = lc.id
```

This would offer better querying opportunity, flexibility and performance in future vs hard referenced codes and crazy looking queries.  If you have an opportunity to adjust your structure early rather than later might be able to do so.  Blend this with MatBailie's "exists" query and you should be good to go for the longer term and just this one time.

Comment: With the OP using the term "variable" in place of "column", I'm inferring that this is likely related to data science / anaytic processing. In such an environment the use of a flat-file format (as per the op) can indeed be both convenient and performant. *(Using a normalised format would require collapsing the multiple rows back in to a single "observation" after the query, a not insignificant overhead. Without more details I wouldn't assert that this structure is categorically inappropriate.)*

Comment: @MatBailie, I agree with you, but with the vagueness of the question, query and codes, just trying to perform alternate, especially if they are new and did not know better on data normalization.  We offer solutions to try and help, but also help to educate and direct depending on real-life needs and longer term benefit.  I do agree if this is some science / analytical purpose.